# Exception trying to connect arduino to a WebSocket Server made with sgcWebSockets

Tags: c++, websocket, arduino, lazarus, freepascal

i have the next question, i have been trying to connect an arduino to a web socket server, the library i use this:

https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets

The arduino get data through modbus a send plain text to the WebSocket Server, it isn't complicated the problem is when i try to connect to the WebSocket Server, i get the exception:

> Error Protocol: arduino  not supported.

here is the arduino code:

```
....
Modbus master(0,1,0);
modbus_t telegram;
unsigned long u32wait;
// arreglo de datos para la comunicacion modbus
int16_t au16data[16];
uint8_t u8state;
....
void setup() {
  pinMode(pD1, INPUT);
  pinMode(pD2, INPUT); 
  pinMode(pD3, INPUT);

  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);

  Serial.begin(57600);

  while(Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0)
  Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");

  webSocket.begin("192.168.1.18", 7500);
  webSocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);

  master.begin( 9600 );
  master.setTimeOut( 2000 );
  u32wait = millis() + 1000;
  u8state = 0;
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  reModbus();
  webSocket.loop();
}
.....
void reModbus() {
  switch( u8state ) {
  case 0: 
    if (millis() > u32wait){
      u8state++; // wait state
      Serial.println("[Modbus] modbus request process has been started.");
    }
    break;
  case 1: 
    telegram.u8id = 21; // slave address
    telegram.u8fct = 3; // function code (this one is registers read)
    telegram.u16RegAdd = 7000; //3042 3146 start address in slave
    telegram.u16CoilsNo = 14; // number of elements (coils or registers) to read
    telegram.au16reg = au16data; // pointer to a memory array in the Arduino

    master.query( telegram ); // send query (only once)
    u8state++;
    Serial.println("[Modbus] modbus query has been send.");
    break;
  case 2:
     master.poll(); // check incoming messages
     if (master.getState() == COM_IDLE) {
        Serial.println("[Modbus] modbus data has been receive.");
        u8state = 0;

        for (int i=0; i <= 6; i++){
          valorsx[i] = convertir(au16data,i*2);
          sensorModbus[i] = String(valorsx[i],6);
        }

        tomadatos1();

        TramaE = 'A'+ sValor1 
               + 'B' + sValor2 
               + 'C' + sD1 
               + 'D' + sD2 
               + 'E' + sD3 
               + 'F' + sensorModbus[0] 
               + 'G' + sensorModbus[1] 
               + 'H' + sensorModbus[2] 
               + 'I' + sensorModbus[3] 
               + 'J' + sensorModbus[4]
               + 'K' + sensorModbus[5]
               + 'L' + sensorModbus[6] 
               + 'M';  

        webSocket.sendTXT(TramaE);
        u32wait = millis() + 100;
     }    
    break;
  }
}
.....
```

looking to the source code of the sgcWebSocket library i use the exception is throw at this place.

```
....
{ RequestURL protocol }
  private
  function DoGetProtocol: string;
{ RequestURL protocol }
....
function TsgcWSConnectionServer.DoGetProtocol: string;
var
  i: Integer;
  oSProtocols, oCProtocols: TsgcDelimitedStringList;
begin
  if FHandshake.Protocols <> '' then
  begin
    oSProtocols := TsgcDelimitedStringList.Create;
    oCProtocols := TsgcDelimitedStringList.Create;
    Try
      oSProtocols.DelimitedText := Protocol;

      oCProtocols.DelimitedText := FHandshake.Protocols;

      for i := 0 to oCProtocols.Count - 1 do
      begin
        if oSProtocols.IndexOf(oCProtocols[i]) > -1 then
        begin
          Result := oCProtocols[i];
          break;
        end;
      end;

      if Result = '' then
        raise TsgcWSException.CreateFmt(S_PROTOCOL_UNSUPPORTED,
          [oCProtocols.Text]);

    Finally
      sgcFree(oCProtocols);
      sgcFree(oSProtocols);
    End;
  end;
end;
```

this function is call at the moment of the handshake, i tried to make a sub protocol using the sample code the documention has:

```
unit ProtocoloArduino;

interface
{$I sgcVer.inc}

{$IFDEF SGC_PROTOCOLS}
uses
  sgcWebSocket_Protocol_Base_Server, Classes, sgcWebSocket_Classes;

type
  TsgcWSProtocol_Arduino = class(TsgcWSProtocol_Server_Base)

  { from TsgcWSComponent }
  protected
   procedure DoEventConnect(aConnection: TsgcWSConnection); override;
   procedure DoEventMessage(aConnection: TsgcWSConnection; const Text: string); override;
   procedure DoEventDisconnect(aConnection: TsgcWSConnection; Code: Integer); override;

  { from TsgcWSComponent }
  public
   constructor Create(aOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;
{$ENDIF}

implementation
{$IFDEF SGC_PROTOCOLS}

constructor TsgcWSProtocol_Arduino.Create(aOwner:TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  // ... here add your protocol name
  FProtocol := 'arduino';
end;

procedure TsgcWSProtocol_Arduino.DoEventConnect(aConnection:TsgcWSConnection);
begin
  inherited;
  // ... add your own code when a client connects to server
end;

procedure TsgcWSProtocol_Arduino.DoEventDisconnect(aConnection: TsgcWSConnection; Code: Integer);
begin
  // ... add your own code when a client disconnects from server
  inherited;
end;

procedure TsgcWSProtocol_Arduino.DoEventMessage(aConnection: TsgcWSConnection; const Text: string);
begin
  inherited;
  // ... process messages received from clients
  // ... you can answer to client using
  WriteData(aConnection.Guid, 'your message');
  // ... you can send a message to all clients using
  BroadCast('your message');
end;
{$ENDIF}
end.
```

but even when i do

```
...
var
  PArduino:TsgcWSProtocol_Arduino;
begin
  PArduino.Create(self.owner);
  ServidorWebSocket.RegisterProtocol(PArduino);
end
...
```

the exception keeps popping up...

if somebody can help me, i would be grateful.

Comment: Why did you tag this question as **C**? The code you're using on Arduino side is written in **C++** which is a completely different language. And your question doesn't have any of that C++!

Comment: sorry i was about to post the code but decided not to (is only start and sendTXT the code), and forgot to remove the tag